# C# 9.0 Record constructor with non-nullable property but with default values

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am trying to define a record type for the following, instead of being a class

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Email {get;set;}
    public string PhoneNo  {get;set;}
    public DateTime UpdatedAt {get;set;} = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Since `UpdatedAt` is a non-nullable field, if I am using the most basic constructor of a record, we will need to pass `DateTime.Now` everytime we call the record. Is there any other way to do it? Instead of doing this:

```
public record Contact(string Name, string Email,string PhoneNo, DateTime UpdatedAt);

var records = new Contact("My Name", "a@abc.com", "123456", DateTime.Now)
```

Comment: What do you want to pass instead?

Comment: `record`s can have default values for parameters just like class constructors can. They have to be compile time constants though, and `DateTime.Now` is a runtime value. Simply add default value to `record` contract like so: `public record Contact(string Name, string Email, string PhoneNo, DateTime UpdatedAt = default);`

Comment: @nbokmans Incorrect - default parameter values for records must be a compile-time constant which `DateTime.Now` isn't unfortunately

Comment: As a sidenote OP - `DateTime.UtcNow` is probably what you also want to use for `UpdatedAt` if it's going inside a DB due to timezone complications

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can give a `record` type a constructor, so add one that takes all 4 properties, but make the `DateTime` nullable and default to `null`. If it's null then have the constructor use `DateTime.Now`. For example:

```
public record Contact
{
    public Contact(string name, string email, string phoneNo, DateTime? updatedAt = null)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Email = email;
        this.PhoneNo = phoneNo;
        this.UpdatedAt = (updatedAt ?? DateTime.Now);
    }

    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Email {get;set;}
    public string PhoneNo  {get;set;}
    public DateTime UpdatedAt {get;set;};
}
```

Comment: I think basically your solution works, just to add on to that. To keep the immutability of a record, change all the `{ get; set; }` to be `{ get; init; }`